# Aggregate Gatling Reports of multiple simulations

Tags: sbt, gatling

Say I have three simulations A, B, and C. After running simulation I get reports of A, B, and C in separate folders with their own separate index.html, how do I aggregate those results to have a single index.html file for those results

Comment: You might be looking for the test aggregation feature of this?  https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Gatling+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the test aggregation feature of this?  https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Gatling+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need this but if anyone else is looking for this, here's the answer.

I moved all the simulation files into a separate folder called simulations inside the gatling results folder and then ran `gatling.bat -ro simulations`

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When we multiple report for eg :-

1. A
2. B
3. C

Go inside the each report folder and copy the Simulation.log file and accumulate in in a single folder(merge-folder name).{simulation1.log ,simulation2.log, ......}

For Windows:-
Navigate to bin folder-------------->
gatling.bat -ro merge

For Mac linux
Navigate to bin folder-------------->
./gatling.sh -ro simulations